# Java String to JS

Tags: java, javascript

so I have a Java Applet and I want to pass a string within the Java Applet to Javascript, how do you do this? Is it even possible? I tried searching google but it only showed examples of passing a  JS string to Java, not Java to JS, the String is in a method

```
public String calc(String ans2)
```

Please help me as I need to pass the String to Javascript so I can edit it further using html codes, Thanks

Comment: Can you make a request from JS to the server and get the variable?

Comment: It's not on a server, the variable is a String, and is called 'ans' if that helps, I have tried `function getJavaString() {
    str = binomial.Main.calc(ans);

    alert(str);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

See [Call Javascript from a Java applet](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html).  It shows 2 techniques for an applet to use/call JS methods.  The 2nd, using `JSObject`, is probably the more reliable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can but you have to make sure the html object tag is setup right as well as both your Java and JavaScript code.

Here's an overview:  http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php